# Move files to folders with same name in Windows

Tags: windows, command-prompt, file-handling

I use following command to copy files to folders with same name.

```
for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do move %x*.* %x\
```

I use `move %x*.* %x\` to move the files to given directory. It doesn't work for files, which has spaces in their filenames, but not sure what to change.

Comment: I tried for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do move "%x*.* %x"\ , but I got syntax error message and files are not moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command uses "DELIMS=" to prevent split.

```
for /f "DELIMS=" %x in ('dir /ad /b') do move "%x*.*" "%x\"
```